# SSL Error showing only from mobile device

Tags: ssl, openssl

I am using a PositiveSSL certificate for my website www.movielee.com
Whenever I browse from my samsung S5 device,it shows

> the security certificate of this site is expired

But never faced any kind of errors while browsing from PC.
Is that an issue with the intermediate certificate?
My browser and phone's time date settings are ok.
Using shared cPanel for the website.If there is a solution to get rid of this for shared hostings managed by cPanel,please let me know.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am using a PositiveSSL certificate for my website 
>   www.movielee.com Whenever I browse from my samsung S5 device,it shows
>
> the security certificate of this site is expired

It appears the certificate is valid (see below). Make sure your Samsung's clock is set correctly.

Also make sure the CRLs associated with the certificate (and its chain) are valid. It looks like a new CRL was published around the time you asked the question:

```
$ curl http://crl.comodoca.com/COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crl | \
       openssl crl -inform DER -text -noout
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  139k  100  139k    0     0   661k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  795k
Certificate Revocation List (CRL):
        Version 2 (0x1)
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: /C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
        Last Update: Aug 25 00:39:57 2014 GMT
        Next Update: Aug 29 00:39:57 2014 GMT
        CRL extensions:
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:90:AF:6A:3A:94:5A:0B:D8:90:EA:12:56:73:DF:43:B4:3A:28:DA:E7

            X509v3 CRL Number: 
                199
Revoked Certificates:
    Serial Number: 07C977601B68FB2A2A061C2491521E5C
        Revocation Date: Feb 20 19:10:49 2014 GMT
    ...
```

---

```
$ openssl s_client -connect www.movielee.com:443 | \
          openssl x509 -text -noout
depth=1 C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = COMODO CA Limited, CN = COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            e6:c8:59:6a:3b:28:2c:ff:af:4c:82:ad:b6:61:d1:2f
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=GB, ST=Greater Manchester, L=Salford, O=COMODO CA Limited, CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
        Validity
            Not Before: Aug 14 00:00:00 2014 GMT
            Not After : Aug 14 23:59:59 2015 GMT
        Subject: OU=Domain Control Validated, OU=PositiveSSL, CN=movielee.com
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:d2:ca:25:8f:bb:f2:35:a1:12:a0:af:f7:f6:ef:
                    39:32:4e:e5:21:32:6d:d0:9a:fc:1f:f1:df:0d:eb:
                    78:65:11:81:57:9b:75:cb:e0:45:2c:d8:55:2f:5e:
                    f3:5e:42:b2:49:99:bb:90:8b:59:15:de:fa:14:9b:
                    cd:b9:d2:48:27:9c:6e:df:fe:16:76:26:d3:ed:f8:
                    63:37:53:47:14:92:51:96:5c:e0:5d:b3:33:71:af:
                    47:b6:45:8b:26:e4:99:b8:ea:1b:41:78:92:f2:ec:
                    c6:4e:87:c5:3c:26:31:1f:b6:d9:32:28:39:31:4b:
                    24:81:61:e2:1a:89:df:e5:cf:04:3a:d8:25:fd:2e:
                    00:77:99:95:16:77:a7:b9:cb:b4:67:2e:21:4a:48:
                    98:49:a8:7d:52:3d:48:a3:a0:46:c9:dd:34:72:57:
                    e3:50:49:cb:66:6f:fb:73:39:71:7f:cd:a7:73:56:
                    4e:87:1f:55:e9:a4:ab:7b:5e:69:78:1a:ba:8b:a1:
                    c9:df:f5:36:51:2d:f9:ba:a1:6d:51:4d:ce:b7:94:
                    43:6b:0b:8e:7e:cd:47:a9:2d:ff:fa:0f:c5:c2:f6:
                    09:cd:99:3a:a0:e0:5e:ed:e0:6c:7a:bf:5f:d1:46:
                    0b:c1:9f:80:2e:6b:bc:37:61:c9:23:4f:df:57:a4:
                    f2:ff
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:90:AF:6A:3A:94:5A:0B:D8:90:EA:12:56:73:DF:43:B4:3A:28:DA:E7

            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                8E:9E:11:F1:21:88:CF:0F:01:80:3B:A4:60:76:B0:76:B1:B6:CA:19
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Key Encipherment
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication
            X509v3 Certificate Policies: 
                Policy: 1.3.6.1.4.1.6449.1.2.1.3.4
                  CPS: https://secure.comodo.net/CPS
                Policy: 2.23.140.1.2.1

            X509v3 CRL Distribution Points: 

                Full Name:
                  URI:http://crl.comodoca.com/COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crl

            Authority Information Access: 
                CA Issuers - URI:http://crt.comodoca.com/COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt
                OCSP - URI:http://ocsp.comodoca.com

            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:movielee.com, DNS:www.movielee.com
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         8b:41:bf:20:da:b5:6a:8e:e9:88:a9:e2:3e:95:05:26:74:40:
         8b:38:1e:3d:be:14:19:5c:38:dc:30:87:94:77:0c:85:8f:7e:
         f3:a6:da:b5:3f:8f:2c:e5:90:bd:e4:f0:6a:20:22:98:6f:f7:
         22:f8:3c:02:25:6b:a0:b6:9d:eb:1a:b2:a1:17:e5:67:2b:2a:
         44:6f:37:70:59:a3:6f:9f:a7:32:50:49:ec:83:c0:4a:eb:65:
         c0:c3:a8:36:42:d1:59:0a:3e:d0:1d:36:d4:75:92:0b:2b:ed:
         a1:31:ca:b8:03:2b:44:91:e6:b2:7f:7b:01:dc:aa:c4:1d:cf:
         a0:d4:c8:da:c7:d2:de:d7:4e:de:49:1f:86:87:c7:5b:1d:ed:
         7f:dd:d0:c5:b2:16:fc:2c:54:13:5d:8e:02:e8:4c:c6:d1:1c:
         46:f4:a1:6d:fc:75:d8:fc:0d:28:f2:3d:6d:ab:e5:f3:5f:56:
         25:8b:9a:21:7a:46:b8:a9:eb:c9:a7:aa:30:a1:14:ec:be:65:
         af:f7:40:bb:5b:a8:f5:31:e3:24:d0:a7:be:22:dd:a6:52:d0:
         9f:30:56:9a:d8:d5:b2:f8:8b:ef:57:da:b4:e8:93:6b:67:25:
         27:a7:9c:8b:c2:32:46:b0:de:46:67:13:b2:05:9b:be:e7:9b:
         02:9f:22:f6
```